# Is the convex hull of closed set in $\mathbb R^{n}$ is closed?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Is convex hull of closed set in $\mathbb R^{n}$ closed?

Answer (score 27):

> Topologically, the convex hull of an open set is always itself open,
>   and the convex hull of a compact set is always itself compact;
>   however, there exist closed sets that do not have closed convex hulls.
>   For instance, the closed set $$
>  \left\{(x,y):y\geq\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right\}\subset\mathbb R^2 $$ has the
>   open upper half-plane as its convex hull.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Relations_to_other_structures).

Comment: Not exactly, the convex hull of a compact set in a infinite dimensional space does not guarantee the compactness. see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156321/convex-hulls-of-compact-sets    But since the question is in $R^n$, so that is correct.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple counterexample: Let $S=(\{0\} \times [0,1] ) \cup ([0,\infty)\times \{0\})$. $S$ is closed since it is the union of two closed sets, however, $\operatorname{co} S = ([0,\infty) \times [0,1)) \cup \{ (0,1)\}$, which is clearly not closed.

If the set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, however, the convex hull is closed. This follows from Carathéodory's theorem which states that any point in $\operatorname{co} S $ can be written in terms of at most $n+1$ elements of $S$ (this is the convex analogue of the fact that any $n+1$ elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be linearly dependent). Hence we can write $\operatorname{co} S = f(S^{n+1} \times \Sigma)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is defined by $f((x_1,...,x_{n+1}, \mu)) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \mu_k x_k$, and $\Sigma$ is the simplex $\Sigma = \{\mu| \mu_k \ge 0, \sum_k \mu_k = 1 \}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $S^{n+1}$ and $\Sigma$ are compact, it follows that $f(S^{n+1} \times \Sigma)$ is compact, hence closed.

Comment: In my opinion, $\text{co}S=([0, \infty)\times[0, 1)\cup(\{0\}\times [0,1])$

Comment: @blindman: That is the same set as I described above. Only the point $(0,1)$ needs to be added. The set $\{0\} \times [0,1)$ is contained in the first set of both of our descriptions.

Comment: @cooper.hat: Thanks. I did not see clearly.