# In a normed space $E$, is the convex envelope of any compact set also compact?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

In a normed space $E$;

One can show that, if $E$ is finte-dimensional, the convex envelope of any compact set is also compact. $(*$)

Is (*) true if $E$ is no longer supposed finite-dimensional ?

Comment: The answer is negative in both cases. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340324/is-the-convex-hull-of-closed-set-in-rn-is-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convex hull of a compact set in an infinite-dimensional Banach space is not necessarily closed, and thus not necessarily compact.  For example, in a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{u_n:\; n \in \mathbb N\}$
consider the compact set $S$ consisting of $0$ and $u_n/n$ for positive integers $n$.  Each point in the convex hull of this set is a linear combination of only finitely many $u_n$.  However, e.g. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} u_n/n$ is in the closure of the convex hull.